# CSS/HTML: text on bar/table?

Tags: html, css

I wish to make something looking like this:

```
http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/5571/bartablestyling.png
```

[image: http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/5571/bartablestyling.png]

(Right now i only have that bar at the top)

When i try to write text, it gets under the profilepicture. 
I dont want to use float:left for it.

How can i make a table that makes the text like that, and the red arrow i drawed, i want to know how to adjust that width between there?

Here's my code for now:

```
<div style="background-image: url(images/notificationShelfBg4.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom; width: auto;">

            <img src="<?php if(!empty($vP["photo_thumb"])) { echo "images/profileimages/".$vP["photo_thumb_small"]; }else{ echo "images/profileimages/noPhoto_thumb.jpg"; } ?>"  style=" border: 2px solid #CCC; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 15px;  margin-bottom: 2px;">


    </span>
    </span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `float: left;`? Also, we don't need to see your PHP code so much as the markup it generates.

Comment: Because then the background image, only make background for the text i insert and under the image too..

Comment: I'm not sure I understood that, but I think you can solve that problem by `float: left;` -ing everything in the bar.

Comment: @Karem: It shouldn't, if you craft your CSS and HTML correctly

Comment: @Yi Jiang, can you help me? I cant seem to find where i did something wrong?

Comment: Just did clearfloat, that did it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one method would be to create a table of 4 columns and 2 rows.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tr>
<td>You're inlogged as:</td>
<td>Sex: Male</td>
<td>Field:1</td>
<td>Field:1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Adrew</td>
<td>Age: 22</td>
<td>Field:1</td>
<td>Field:1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

then with css you can modify the width of the cell. for example you can use

```
td {width:200px;}
```

or you can use a class in every cell like `<td class="cell">Sex: Male</td>` and then apply a style on this class with css like .cell `{width:200px;}`.

Of course I still believe that you can use floats and with some tricks (if there is need) to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML markup:

```
<div class="profile">
    <img src="path/to/your/img.png" alt="Example's Avatar" />
    <p class="login-info">You are logged in as: <span class="username">Example User</span></p>
    <ul class="user-info">
        <li>Gender: Male</li>
        <li>Age: 24</li>
        <li>Member since: 24 Aug 2009</li>
        <li>Currently wearing: Pink T-Shirt</li>
        <li>Email: example@example.com</li>
        <li>Another field: Value 1</li>
        <li>Drinking: Coffee</li>
        <li>Mug collection: 300</li>
        <li>Another field: Value 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

We are using a mixture of list, paragraphs and images to get the markup we want. For instance, the list of fields is obviously a list, so we use the `ul` unordered list element here. We're also using the `img` tag here instead of `background-image` because the profile image is important and contains actual information.

```
.profile {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #333 url('path/to/gradient.png') repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    width: 960px;
}

.profile img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: block;
}

.profile .login-info, .profile .user-info li, .profile .user-info, .profile img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.profile .login-info {
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.profile .user-info {
    width: 665px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

.profile .user-info li {
    width: 190px;
}

.profile .login-info .username {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

The CSS is separated from the markup - this is important, as we want to keep content and styling separate. Basically, using the `class`es we have added inside the HTML, we give the contents of the profile styling information that will cause it to be presented in the manner you specified in the picture.

We float almost everything in that profile box, then give them specific widths so that they'll move up next to each other in columns, and finally give them a margin to the right to give them some space between the columns.

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/stEkY/